# selvin's code for integration of linkedin in android

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

This is done based on selvin's coding, but it doesnt work for me, that is message is not getting posted on the linked wall in android. after login stays in the same page.
This is the code  `public class LITestActivity extends Activity {

```
// /change keysssssssssssssssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!

static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "key";

static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "secret";

static final String APP_NAME = "abc";
static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";
static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = String.format("%s://%s",
        OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME, OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST);
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM = "oauth_problem";

final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
        .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,
                CONSUMER_SECRET);
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
        .newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

static final String OAUTH_PREF = "LIKEDIN_OAUTH";
static final String PREF_TOKEN = "token";
static final String PREF_TOKENSECRET = "token secret";
static final String PREF_REQTOKENSECRET = "requestTokenSecret";

TextView tv = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token = pref.getString(PREF_TOKEN, null);
    final String tokenSecret = pref.getString(PREF_TOKENSECRET, null);
    if (token == null || tokenSecret == null) {
        startAutheniticate();
    } else {
        showCurrentUser(new LinkedInAccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
    }

}

void startAutheniticate() {
    final LinkedInRequestToken liToken = oAuthService
            .getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    final String uri = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
    getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, liToken.getTokenSecret())
            .commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    i.putExtra("sms_body", "Welcome to Rebuix, http://www.rebuix.com");
    startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Successfuly posted: " ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

void finishAuthenticate(final Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        final String problem = uri.getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM);
        if (problem == null) {
            final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF,
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService
                    .getOAuthAccessToken(
                            new LinkedInRequestToken(uri
                                    .getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN),
                                    pref.getString(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET,
                                            null)),
                            uri.getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER));
            pref.edit()
                    .putString(PREF_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken())
                    .putString(PREF_TOKENSECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret())
                    .remove(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();
            showCurrentUser(accessToken);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Appliaction down due OAuth problem: " + problem,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

    }
}

void clearTokens() {
    getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .remove(PREF_TOKEN).remove(PREF_TOKENSECRET)
            .remove(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();
}

void showCurrentUser(final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {
    final LinkedInApiClient client = factory
            .createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
    try {
        final Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // here you can do client API calls ...
    // client.postComment(arg0, arg1);
    // client.updateCurrentStatus(arg0);
    // or any other API call (this sample only check for current user
    // and shows it in TextView)
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        tv.setText(p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getFirstName());
    } catch (LinkedInApiClientException ex) {
        clearTokens();
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Appliaction down due LinkedInApiClientException: "
                        + ex.getMessage()
                        + " Authokens cleared - try run application again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    finishAuthenticate(intent.getData());
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below URL to integration of social network like facebook, [Twitter & LinkedIn](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr)